# PL/SQL case statement throwing PLS-00103 error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a calculator in PL/SQL using a case statement:

```
DECLARE
    a NUMBER ;
    b NUMBER;
    v_option varchar2(10);
BEGIN

    a :=&variableA;
    b :=&variableB;
    v_option :=&variableC;
    case when  v_option ='+' then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sum = '|| (a+b));
    case when  v_option ='-' then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('subtraction = '|| (a-b));
    case when  v_option ='*' then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('multiplication = '|| (a*b));
    case when  v_option ='/' then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('multiplication = '|| (a*b));
   else
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Wrong operator entered');
    
END;
```

This is giving me:

> ORA-06550: line 20, column 4:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: case

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is giving compilation error-----Error report -
ORA-06550: line 20, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   case
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Please add new information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63087815/edit). I've done it this time, and made a few formatting changes.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three immediate problems. Firstly when you have a substitution variable that is not numeric then you need to enclose is in single quotes, either when entering it or more usefully when using it; so (with your original name, which isn't very descriptive):

```
v_option := '&variableC';
```

Secondly your division case uses `*` instead of `/`, which is just a typo.

Thirdly, and most importantly, your case construct is wrong; you have multiple `case` keywords instead of just new `when`/`else`, and you are missing the `end case;` to complete the flow - which is what causes the error you see, as it sees the final `END;` when it's expecting to see `end case;` at that point.

So putting that together:

```
DECLARE
  a NUMBER ;
  b NUMBER;
  v_option varchar2(10);
BEGIN

  a := &first_value;
  b := &second_value;
  v_option := '&option';

  case
    when v_option = '+' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sum = '|| (a+b));
    when v_option = '-' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('subtraction = '|| (a-b));
    when v_option = '*' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('multiplication = '|| (a*b));
    when v_option = '/' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('division = '|| (a/b));
    else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Wrong operator entered');
  end case;

END;
/
```

As you are always looking at the same value in the `when` clauses you could simplify using the alternative syntax:

```
  case v_option
    when '+' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sum = '|| (a+b));
    when '-' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('subtraction = '|| (a-b));
    when '*' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('multiplication = '|| (a*b));
    when '/' then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('division = '|| (a/b));
    else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Wrong operator entered');
  end case;
```

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CASE-statement.html) shows the case statement syntax, and the difference between searched and simple case statements.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5a0ba66fca2766d04fb51425df5cc642) with fixed values instead of substitution variables.